# Cannot Install App from Google Play : Error 504

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have published my app on Google Play.  It can be downloaded, but it cannot be installed successfully.  I've tried installing the app on multiple devices, but the problem is same in all of them. I get the same error code, `error 504`.  What is the problem?

Comment: can i have link of that app?

Comment: yes sure  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hamza.ghazlani

Comment: seem wrong url!

Comment: Corrected grammar mistakes. Made the question more clear.